# compare driving distance from JSON array

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I'm using `googledistancematrix` api for calculating distance from login user to all my fields of db. That's my controller code.

```
$field_list = Field::all();
for ($i=0; $i < count($field_list); $i++)
    { 
        $destination = $field_list[$i]['latitude'] . "," . $field_list[$i]['longitude'];
        $details = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&mode=driving&sensor=false";
        $json = file_get_contents($details);
        $details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        if (count($details['destination_addresses']) > 0 )
        {
            $distance = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
            $field_list[$i]->distance = $distance;
        }
    }
```

By this i'm getting following response:

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a35cedef327244ceb19ed35a2a4c8ddf

But i want to show only those fields whose `distance < or = 30 mins`.
Thanks

Comment: Use the `value` field in the response from google to sort by adding it like `$field_list[$i]->distance_value = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value']`. The `value` field is the duration in seconds.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#rows

Comment: `text: 11 mins` and `value:630` according to this [response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d59c81ca6d8b4a5680bf5114b0676951)

Comment: According to documentation value is the distance in seconds but 11 mins = 660 seconds. But it returns 630, that's why i used texture data.

Comment: Well thats because it is rounding up... It doesn't make sense to use a fraction of a minute when using textual data. The value is actually more accurate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)**

```
$min = strtotime("30 mins");
$val = strtotime("0 hours 10 mins");

echo $min <= $val? "yes":"no";
```

([here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27fc0021c026c987e535767ece0cb3c5c835dbd7) if you want to test it)

in your case

```
if (count($details['destination_addresses']) > 0 ){
    $min = strtotime("30 mins");
    $distance = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

    if($min <= strtotime($distance)){
           //do your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Why parse the text when Google offers an integer value for the duration?

Comment: where? Its returning me this responce [response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d59c81ca6d8b4a5680bf5114b0676951)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple matter to convert the time to seconds using strtotime() as follows:

```
$time=strtotime($details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']);
if (($time-time()>1800) {
    // ignore this element, probably in loop so do a continue
}
```

This is based on using your example line above which is only for a single element. You would need to wrap it with a loop and perform the calculation for each element.